# Calculating Omega for algorithm efficiency

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

I am having trouble understanding calculating the efficiency of an algorithm. Here is one of my problems. Can someone help explain what method is used for figuring this out? The book is very confusing and does not spend a lot of time on this.

Find the appropriate Ω relationship between the functions n^3 and 3n^3 - 2n2 + 2 and find the constants c and n0

I know that there isnt much difference between n^3 and 3n^3 but I am not sure how to find the constants c and n0;

Comment: Generally constants are ignored in efficiency calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The functions n<sup>3</sup> and 3n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>2</sup> + 2 are actually Θ of one another, meaning that they grow at the same rates. It should be possible to lower-bound each of the functions with the other.

In the first direction, notice that

> 3n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>2</sup> + 2
>
> ≥ 3n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>2</sup>
>
> ≥ 3n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>3</sup>
>
> = n<sup>3</sup>

Therefore, if you pick c = 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 0, then we get that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> that 3n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>2</sup> + 2 ≥ cn<sup>3</sup>, so 3n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>2</sup> + 2 = Ω(n<sup>3</sup>)

I'll leave the reverse direction as the proverbial Exercise to the Reader. :-)

Hope this helps!